# Core Data: import a tree structure with find or insert / duplicate entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, core-data, tree

I have a list of Places from a rails app that I'm trying to import in an iOS5 app. Each Place has a parent which is a Place itself.

I'm trying to import that JSON data with Core Data using a dictionary

```
- (void)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    self.placeId = [dictionary valueForKey:@"id"]; 
    id parent = [dictionary objectForKey:@"parent"];
    if (parent && parent != [NSNull null]) {
        NSDictionary *parentDictionary = parent;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"placeId = %@", [parentDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];
        NSArray *matching = fetchedWithPredicate(@"Place", self.managedObjectContext, predicate, nil);
        if ([matching count] > 0) {
            self.parent = [matching objectAtIndex:0];
        } else {
            self.parent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            [self.parent initWithDictionary:parentDictionary];
        }
    }
}
```

fetchedWithPredicate is a method defined as such

```
NSArray* fetchedWithPredicate(NSString *entityName, NSManagedObjectContext *context, NSPredicate *predicate, NSError **error) {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:error];
    return result;
}
```

I also have a validation method in Place.m to make sure I don't create to place with the same placeId (placeId is the id on the server side).

```
- (BOOL)validatePlaceId:(id *)value error:(NSError **)error {
    if (*value == nil)
        return YES;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"placeId = %@ AND (NOT self IN %@)", *value, [NSArray arrayWithObject:self]];
    NSArray *matching = fetchedWithPredicate(@"Place", self.managedObjectContext, predicate, error);
    if ([matching count] > 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

To import the data, I fetch all places from the server, returned in JSON format.
Each Place has its own information, plus a child node with informations about the parent, which means that each parent of multiple children will appear multiple times. It looks like

```
{ "id": 73, 
  "name": "Some place", 
  "parent": { "id": 2,
              "name": "Parent's name"}
}
```

I thought the above code which does kind of a "find or create", with a fetch including unsaved changes, would be alright.
But it still attempt to create multiple entries for some places (and fails to since there's a validation in place). Looking deeper, it indeed insert different core data objects for the same placeId (different pointers), but I don't know why.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you already have a unique index on id (which is good obviously). I think it is that you are not saving the newly inserted creations to core data prior to expecting it to be returned via fetch. The simple (if perhaps not too performant depending on having lots of rows) would be to add a `saveContext` call right after each object is inserted/inited.

Another way would be to do it in two passes, first entirely in memory where you create a separate dictionary where the key is the id, and the object is the value. That way you'd be able to ensure each id was only in there once. After they're all in that dictionary, you can then easily (or easier, perhaps) add them all to Core Data.

Comment: I thought that having "setIncludesPendingChanges:YES" in my fetch was enough to get objects in the current context even though I didn't save the context. Do you know why this would be wrong ?
Unless there's an answer to that, your suggestion of a separate dictionary is what I'll do.

Comment: I think pendingChanges (guessing here) might only know if you add in regular `[moc processPendingChanges]` calls for each loop, although that should get called for you regularly if you're on the main thread/run loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit more investigation, it's due to the fact that I was sorting my data by name...

So if a place A had 5 children, and 3 of them had a name that was before A's name, the code would:

1. create those 3 children with a parent that don't have any parent itself (because my json doesn't return infos about the parent's parent)
2. create A
3. create the 2 other children with A as parent (probably because of the way it's sorted, but that doesn't change the conclusion), so a parent that does have a parent

Now we have 2 objects A, one with a parent, and one without a parent, which Core Data consider has 2 objects.

The easy way out: my tree is a nested set, so I just have to sort places by the left value, and this way I'll always create parents before children.

The "sort by name" wasn't part of my description, so I'll leave scc's answer as accepted :)